# I want to validate that input-label has a value if other input-control has set certain value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

As I said in the title, I have a dropdown list with 2 values - yes and no, and another input label where you can write freely. I want to validate that if the user chose "yes", also the input label is filled and vice versa - if "no" was chosen I want to make sure that the input label is empty.

For making sure, that if "no" was chosen label will be empty, I tried simply blocking the label when "no" is chosen but it is not enough as a user can choose "yes" then write something and switch back to "no"

```html
<div class="select-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'select-wrapper-blocked': isNotAdmin()}">
            <select class="input-control" [(ngModel)]="booleanVariable">
                <option value="false">No</option>
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col form-input" [ngClass]="{'form-input-blocked': isNotAdmin()}">
        <p class="input-label">
            Some text
        </p>
        <input class="input-control" [(ngModel)]="stringVariable" />
    </div>
```

Comment: to make a custom validator in Template drive form you need create a directive, see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms. If only want if you select true, add required, you simply `<input [required]="booleanVariable?true:null">`, but this don't fullfit with your another requeriment: if "no" must be empty

Comment: try this with two way binding and apply *ngIf to able and disable the input box. I think this will work.

Comment: It all works initially, but when I switch to "yes" then back to "no", the input box doesn't dissapear again

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap  input label  in a `<span>` and display it only when user selects "yes" i.e `booleanVariable` is `true`

Try like this:

```
<p class="input-label">
    <span *ngIf="booleanVariable">  Some text </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, it only deactivates the input label, but activates it no matter wheter you choose yes or no, and it doesn't solve main problem - checking if textbox is filled

Comment: I got confused, can you clarify when you want to display input-label

Comment: I want to display input-label when "yes" is chosen, but your answer makes the dropdown list have no initial value and shows the input-label no matter what you choose

Comment: When I choose "no" the onput-label shows, but when i reload the page it is hidden until I choose yes again
I don't know why it doesn't hide when I choose no after choosing yes :/

Comment: The code is shared will not effect the dropdown list in any way, This should be something else. You can also set a default value of dropdown from ts. You can share a stackbiltz. it would be easier to help